# JSON из "одинаковых" строк

Tags: json, javascript, php

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема: через post пересылается строка json и расшифровывается. Аналогично создается такой же массив, шифруется в строку json и тоже расшифровывается. Внешне строки одинаковы, но в первом случае строка не разворачивается в массив. Как удалось установить, в строку пишутся лишние 90 байт. Откуда они могли взяться?
Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
var_dump(iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $_POST['data']));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data'], true));

echo '<br><br>';

$ar = array(
    1 => array(
        1 => '11',
        2 => '222',
        4 => '4444',
        'sid' => '1',
    ),
);
var_dump($ar = json_encode($ar));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(json_decode($ar, true));

/*
Вывод:

string(137) "{"1":{"1":"11","2":"222","4":"4444","sid":"1"}}" 
NULL

string(47) "{"1":{"1":"11","2":"222","4":"4444","sid":"1"}}" 
array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=> string(3) "222" [4]=> string(4) "4444" ["sid"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Тип ошибки:
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - Syntax error
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поржал над собственной невнимательностью, спасибо...
Правильный ответ: у меня `$_POST` обрабатывается функцией htmlspecialchars(), поэтому строка приходила с заменой кавычек. А это при выводе на экран заметно не было.
Короче, `$_POST['data'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data']);` решило проблему. =)

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Правильно - просто **не обрабатывать $_POST функцией htmlspecialchars**!

Answer (score 0):

У меня было еще веселее - двойные кавычки экранировались из `$_POST` автоматически при написании плагина WP - пришлось предварительно обрабатывать `$_POST`-переменную функцией `str_replace()`

Comment: В 2016м до сих пор используют magic quotes?!

Comment: Сюрприз от Xampp